# Return results according to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I've had a problem with my code for days. I claim to be inexperienced with Django. I would like to get the results according to a specific "CalendarGroups", for example all calendars only of a specific CalendarGroups. The id of the group on which to filter the calendars I would like to pass it through url whit "goup_id".

In Url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.hello, name='hello'), #Prova
    url(r'^home/$', views.GroupCalendarView.as_view(), name='home'), #Prova
    url(r'^home/(?P<group_id>\d+)/$', views.CalendarsOfGroupView.as_view(), name='calendar_view'),
]
```

In models.py:

```
class CalendarGroups(models.Model):
    GRP = (
       ('Amazon', 'Amazon'),
       ('VICHY', 'VICHY'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 155, blank=True, null=True)
    
    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.name} </a>'
   

class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #created_by
    group = models.ForeignKey(CalendarGroups, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='')
 
    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:calendar_view', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.name} </a>'
```

In views.py:

```
class GroupCalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = CalendarGroups
    template_name = 'cal/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #print (context)
        return context

class CalendarsOfGroupView(generic.ListView):
    
    model = Calendar
    template_name = 'cal/calendarOfGroup.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
               
        return context
```

This is my current code, I don't know how I can use what I pass through "group_id" in views.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class CalendarsOfGroupView(generic.ListView): 
      model = Calendar 
      template_name = 'cal/calendarOfGroup.html' 

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
          context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
          group_id = self.kwargs['group_id']
          # create var to hold all objects that do not have name==group_id
          object_list = Calendar.objects.exclude(name=group_id)
          # update the context
          context.update({'object_list': object_list})          
          return context
```

Edit: Filter the Calendar objects to **include** only those that match `group_id`

```py
class CalendarsOfGroupView(generic.ListView): 
      model = Calendar 
      template_name = 'cal/calendarOfGroup.html' 

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
          context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
          group_id = self.kwargs['group_id']
          # create var to hold all objects that do have name==group_id
          object_list = Calendar.objects.filter(name=group_id)
          # update the context
          context.update({'object_list': object_list})          
          return context
```

Comment: When using ```.exclude()```, you enter the ```group_id``` you do not want to see. If you want to see only objects with the ```group_id```, then use ```.filter(Calendar.name=group_id)```

Comment: Thanks @Alec but I have this syntax error: "SyntaxError: keyword can't be a an expression" for "(" in the line:"object_list = Calendar.objects.filter(Calendar.name=group_id) "

Comment: My mistake on that. The parameter inside ```.filter()``` should not include the object name. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`group_id` or any other URL parameters will be available in `kwargs`:

```
group_id = self.kwargs['group_id']
```

You can access it in your `get_queryset` method or any other methods available for your class.